# Cast ObservableCollection of (unknown)

Tags: .net, collections, casting, ienumerable

There is an collection object. I need to catch **each single object of this collection** to work with that single object.

I have determined the incomming object with the interfaces:

```
TypeOf Src Is System.Collections.IList = TRUE 
TypeOf Src Is System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object) = TRUE
```

The object in real is

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of OwnSpecialClass)
```

When casting this incomming object

```
NewCollection = CType(MySourceCollection, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of Object))
```

it throws the exception (GERMAN):

> Das Objekt des Typs
>   "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[OwnSpecialClass]"
>   kann nicht in Typ
>   "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Object]"
>   umgewandelt werden.

**How to cast this collection to any ObservableCollection if the OwnSpecialClass is not available and just known as object.**

My tests:

[image: Exception screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you are asking for so if not I apologize but here's how you can change from a more specific observable collection down to a regular collection, and vice-versa as well. It's a bit of an expensive operation.

```
Dim observableCollection As New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)()
Dim collection As New System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of Object)(observableCollection.Cast(Of Object)().ToList())

'or in reverse...'

Dim collection As New System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of Object)()
Dim observableCollection As New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)(collection.Cast(Of String)())
```

Comment: `observableCollection` in your example (first code line) is transported as `Object` only and the question is now, how to cast it into the `ObservableCollection` (named `collection` second code line in your example)

Answer (score 0):

The use of the following code does the work

```
 If TypeOf Src Is System.Collections.IList Then

     Dim IListTmp As System.Collections.IList = CType(Src, System.Collections.IList)
     Dim IListTmpItems(IListTmp.Count - 1) As Object
     IListTmp.CopyTo(IListTmpItems, 0)

     For Each O As Object In IListTmpItems
          'Whatever you want to do with that object now.... ex: result = result & O.ToString() & "|"
     Next
 End If
```

But converter is not huge performant because each items needs to be casted.